# Ubuntu 22:04 won't start after deleting Windows partition

Tags: partitioning, systemd, reboot, boot-repair, system

This is what it's showing.

[image: This is what it's showing]

There was no use for Windows and I needed more free space for the Linux partition, so I decided to delete the Windows partition from Ubuntu Disks utility. After I restarted Ubuntu it started giving me errors.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please boot into a live session, run `GParted` and take a screenshot of what it shows and edit it into your question.